# Use classes provided in app.module in child modules

Tags: angular

I am building a webapp with Angular and I am using the OwlDateTime picker to get some user input. I want to change the 'set' and 'cancel' label text.

According to the creator, this can be done by creating this class

```
@Injectable()
export class DefaultIntl extends OwlDateTimeIntl {

    /** A label for the cancel button */
    cancelBtnLabel= 'Annuleren';

    /** A label for the set button */
    setBtnLabel= 'Kiezen';

    /** A label for the range 'from' in picker info */
    rangeFromLabel= 'Van';

    /** A label for the range 'to' in picker info */
    rangeToLabel= 'Tot';

    /** A label for the hour12 button (AM) */
    hour12AMLabel= 'AM';

    /** A label for the hour12 button (PM) */
    hour12PMLabel= 'PM';
};
```

and providing it like this

```
providers: [{ provide: OwlDateTimeIntl, useClass: DefaultIntl }]
```

in my modules.

This works fine if I do it in all my seperate modules for each part of my app, but is there a way where I can only do this once in my app.module, and have these changes in all my other modules aswell?

Comment: This should work in `AppModule`. You mean it doesn't at all?

Comment: @LppEdd No it doesn't for work for me when I only have it in my app.module. If I do this in my (for instance) calendar.module then the changes get made in all components that are "under" that module

Comment: I suppose those modules are lazy, right?

Comment: Indeed they are, I lazy load those in my app-routing.module.

Comment: Are you importing the same `OwlDateTimeModule` again in the lazy modules?

Comment: Yes I am, does that mean I am overriding the settings that are applied to them in the `app.module`?

Comment: Thank you for the quick responses! I am going to give this a try

Comment: Ok, I wrote something stupid hahaha
You need to provide the Module in the lazy loaded ones, otherwise you won't be able to use the exported classes.

Comment: I couldn't quite get it to work so I am happy that you replied anyway! Do you mean I should still import the `OwlDateTimePicker` modules and provide the exported class in each feature module?

Comment: See answer, instead of the StackBlitz.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a wrapper module. For example

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [OwlDateTimeModule, OwlNativeDateTimeModule],
  exports: [OwlDateTimeModule],
  providers: [{ provide: OwlDateTimeIntl, useClass: DefaultIntl }]
})
export class OwlModule { }
```

And import it in the root module

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [..., OwlModule],
  ...
})
export class AppModule { }
```

and in the lazy ones

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [..., OwlModule],
  ...
})
export class LazyModule { }
```

---

Normally libraries expose a `forRoot` and `forChild` method.
`forRoot` constructs a `ModuleWithProviders` which exposes Services, while `forChild` does not do that, leveraging the root one.
An example is the Ngxs's [NgxsModule](https://github.com/ngxs/store/blob/e461af994b75586a30bee51d7b784f162f542428/packages/store/src/module.ts).

Unfortunately it seems this library isn't really well thought for that.

Comment: Thank you! This prevents me from having to declare the DefaultIntl class in each seperate module which makes the modules much cleaner!